# how to save and view my pdf online

Tags: html, web-services, pdf, web, joomla

Does anyone know any site that i can save my `pdf file` and `view` it?

I want to do is get the URL of the view page of my pdf so i can embed it in my Joomla.

The reason I'm doing this cause i got a specific pdf file that wont show in my Joomla article even though i used a pdf plugin already. The only solution i have is get the saved pdf file URL on that site and use it t embed it in my Joomla article.

so instead of saving the pdf to my joomla

```
{pdf=http://www.example.org/images/ADS/ads.pdf|820|820}
```

I'l' use the URL of that website to view my pdf in my Joomla article.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can use joomla extention [something like this](http://demos.techjoomla.com/jomsocial/index.php/more/pdf-embed.html) to manage and view PDF

Or else use something like mediafire [mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/upgrade/) to upload your pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/3115

It works perfectly.
In the article edditing, it adds an attach button.

It worked like a charm.

Do not forget to set the file as public when you upload it.

Furthermore,  enable  the installed plugin.